# How to count the number of occurrences based on uniques values in another columns dataframe in pandas? Please Consider the below example

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
protocol results:
tcp       0
tcp       1
udp       1
udp       0
tcp       1
icmp      0
```

I want the output by counting:

```
[protocol]  [frequency]  [No. of 0's in results] [No. of 1's in results 
tcp          3            1                        2
udp          2            1                        1
icmp         1            1                        0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and some data cleaning for `DataFrame` and then add second column by [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) with `sum`:

```
df = (pd.crosstab(df.protocol, df.results)
        .add_prefix('No ')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
df.insert(1, 'freq', df.sum(axis=1))
print (df)
  protocol  freq  No 0  No 1
0     icmp     1     1     0
1      tcp     3     1     2
2      udp     2     1     1
```